# Get value of object literal key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, literals

I've got an object literal inside an array and I'm trying to access the keys: Name and Price.

Here is my object:

```
var ProductList = [  
    { "1": { Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99" } },  
    { "2": { Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99" } },  
    { "3": { Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99" } },  
    { "4": { Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99" } }  
  ];
```

The numbers 1,2,3,4 are the product item ID's, so I'm trying to do this:

`console.log(ProductList[1].Name);`

But it just doesn't seem to be working.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: `ProductList[0]['1'].Name`

Comment: It has to be ProductList[0]["1"]["Name"]. Not sure why you'd set it up that way. Why wouldn't you have the objects like this instead: `{ ID: "1", Name: "Name", Price: "0.99" }` ?

Comment: @EfrainReyes If I set it up that way, how would I access the Name and Price from the object? Assuming I want to access by ID

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: Since you are storing the hashes in an array. It seems, I could be wrong, that you want to access array elem position - 1 , per your product ID's. IF your ID's were varies, ie.. 123, 587, ABC987, then the following wouldn't work.

```
var ProductList = [

    {"1": {Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99"}},

    {"2": {Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99"}},

    {"3": {Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99"}},

    {"4": {Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99"}}

];


var prodRef = 1; // in this example

ProductList[prodRef - 1][prodRef].Name;
```

I would personally do the following, in setting up your object.

```
var ProductList = {

    "1": {Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99"},

    "2": {Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99"},

    "3": {Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99"},

    "4": {Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99"}

};

   // so, you can just always access it via your productID.
    var prodRef = 4;
    ProductList[prodRef].Name
```

Answer (score 2):

### Recommended Approach

I would recommend modifying the objects in the array to include an `ID` attribute.  With this attribute in place you can use the `filter` method on the array to find elements by their `ID` property.

```
var ProductList = [
    {ID: "11", Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99"},
    {ID: "22", Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99"},
    {ID: "33", Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99"},
    {ID: "44", Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99"}
];

function findById(arr, id){
    var results = arr.filter(function(e){
        return e.ID == id;
    });
    return (results.length) ? results[0]:undefined;

}
```

### Orignal Array

If you must stick with the original array the following can be applied.

You must access the object using the property name associated with each object in the array:

```
console.log(ProductList[1]["2"].Name);
```

If you can't change the structure of these objects I would make a helper function:

```
var ProductList = [
{"1": {Name: "Item name", Price: "0.99"}},
{"2": {Name: "Item name", Price: "0.19"}},
{"3": {Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99"}},
{"4": {Name: "Item name", Price: "8.99"}}
];

function getInternal(arr, index){
    return arr[index][index+1];
}

var obj = getInternal(ProductList, 1);
console.log(obj.Name);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/68WDZ/

Comment: "*SyntaxError: Unexpected number*": should be `ProductList[1]["2"].Name` or `ProductList[1][2].Name`

Comment: Like @p.s.w.g. said, you need to make sure it understands that you're chaining the accessor.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks for making me aware of that, I only tested the helper function which worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for an Object instead of an Array.

```
var productList = {
    "1": { name: "Millenium Falcon", price: 20 },
    "2": { name: "Storm Troopers", price: 5.99 },
    ...
}

console.log(productList["1"].name == "Millenium Falcon");
console.log(productList["2"].price == 5.99);
```

Of course, if you cannot change the data you got, you must use productList[0]["1"].Name

Comment: I tried that earlier and got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ` at line 1 (`var productList = {`)for some reason. Hmm

Comment: Sorry, I wrote 5,99 instead of 5.99. This should work...

Comment: sorry Bart, it did work, what I had done was wrap each line in a new object, giving:

`var productList = {  
    {"1": { name: "Millenium Falcon", price: 20 }},  
    {"2": { name: "Storm Troopers", price: 5.99 }},  
    ...  
}`